# Preparing a real-time app to save state data for unforseen events such as unexpected shutdown, crashes, etc

Tags: c#, .net, crash, shutdown

I have an app that conducts an interactive exam session for students on pre-configured computers without an internet connection. The app records user input, system metrics, etc. during the exam and follows an incremental approach to saving this data so that a sudden crash or power outage does not destroy the session data for the entire exam.

The app serializes data every second to a new file with a time stamp and compiles everything together at the end of the session to mark it as an ATOMIC transaction. This works fine.

What I want to do is make the app more robust in responding to unexpected scenarios such as shutdown-initiation triggered by a UPS, the user themselves accidentally kicking the power down button (it happens), etc. Of course I understand that not much can be done if the OS crashes or the power line breaks.

What I am looking for is:

- a comprehensive list of events to subscribe to such as shutdown initiation, battery level critical for laptops, etc.
- How to subscribe to these events under .NET 4 (any language).

Comment: What's the problem with your current solution? Continously saving (including flushing buffers) will guard both against app crashes, clean OS shutdowns and catastrophic OS shutdowns (crash or power).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do nothing with power off. Application.UnhandledException and Close will trap anything you have a vague chance at dealing with which would include a close signal from a soon to be exhausted battery, or a UPS kicking in.